# How to filter JArray?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I have a JArray as below, how to filter it by "to" and "from"?, I have tried the following:

```
JArray ja_test = (JArray)(ja_chat
    .Children<JArray>()
    .Where(o => (int)o["data"]["from"] == 49 && (int)o["data"]["to"] == 10));
```

but it throws:

> Unable to cast object of type `WhereEnumerableIterator'1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray]`
> to type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`

how to achieve this?

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "to": 49,
      "from": 50,
      "text": "Hi Dev",
      "files": [],
      "msg_id": "__chat__",
      "datetime": "2022-05-22 12:23:14"
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "to": 49,
      "from": 10,
      "text": "Hello Dev",
      "files": [],
      "msg_id": "__chat__",
      "datetime": "2022-05-22 12:23:14"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is essentially a typo: you're casting the result of `.Where(...)`, not `ja_chat`. You need `((JArray)ja_chat)` for that.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar no, it's not typo

Comment: It's not a typo? What is it then? Are you trying to materialise (build a list or array) from the result of your query (the `.Where`)? Do you actually require a `JArray` result?

Comment: You are trying to cast a LINQ query to a JArray - that fails because it doesn't make sense. What you should do depends on what you want to do with the results of the query

Comment: There - I edited your question so it's easier to understand what @DiplomacyNotWar said. Notice that it's exactly the same as what it was, the added `()` are optional and doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to  parse json at first. Try this, it will return an array of JObject

```
var JArray jaChat = JArray.Parse(json);

JObject[] jaTest = jaChat.Where( o =>
        (int)o["data"]["from"] == 10 && (int)o["data"]["to"] == 49)
        .Select(o=> (JObject)o).ToArray();
```

or if you want a JArray, you have to convert JObject[] to JArray

```
    JArray jaTest1 = JArray.FromObject(jaTest);

   // or from json

    JArray jaTest = JArray.FromObject( jaChat.Where(o =>
    (int)o["data"]["from"] == 10 && (int)o["data"]["to"] == 49));
```